# How to pass Class type of <T> in a generic method

Tags: java

I am trying to write a generic method so I can reuse it for multiple Request and response types. This is the non-generic method

```
 public ReservationBookingResponse invokeService(String endPoint, ReservationBookingRequest reservationBookingRequest, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws  APIException {

ResponseEntity<ReservationBookingResponse> response = null;
try {  
    String authToken = getAuthToken(restTemplate, httpServletRequest);
    HttpEntity<ReservationBookingRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<ReservationBookingRequest>(reservationBookingRequest, addAuthorizationHeader(authToken));
    response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endPoint, entity, ReservationBookingResponse.class);  

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new  APIException(e);
}

return response.getBody();
}
```

This is the generic method I wrote

```
public default T invoke(String endPoint, K requestBean, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws  APIException {

    RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<T> response = null;
    try {
            String authToken = getAuthToken(restTemplate, httpServletRequest);
            HttpEntity<K> entity   = new HttpEntity<K>(requestBean, addAuthorizationHeader(authToken));
        response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endPoint, entity, T);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new  APIException(e);
    }
    return  response.getBody();
    }
```

Now the problem is in  `response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endPoint, entity, T);` 
I am getting an exception "T cannot be resolved to a type" in the non generic(former) method `response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endPoint, entity, ReservationBookingResponse.class);`  this works fine.

Now I can not do **T.class** as it is not allowed. Can someone please tell me how to pass `Class<T>` to the method.

This is what the postforEntity method expects

```
@Override
    public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)
            throws RestClientException {
```

Comment: You would have to have actual `Class` object, no way around it, pretty sure. So it depends on where you get `T` from - you have to save reference to class in the same place. For example, in constructor or method signature.

Comment: Well, you can get a `Class<T>` object from a variable of type `T`. You just call `getClass()` on it and cast the result. However, it is not type safe, as it is not guaranteed to be the same class - it could also be a subtype. I only recall doing it with enums. Not quite the case here anyway - the `postEntity` is where the object is created.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be given the `Class<T>` at some point by the caller.

The most straightforward way is to require the caller to provide the class when calling `invoke`. It is what Piotr Wilkin suggests and what you did in your answer. It however creates more boilerplate than needed, and there is a better option.

Since `T` is a generic of the whole object, you could provide the `Class<T>` to the constructor, like:

```
private final Class<T> type; // some prefer naming like clazz

public MyClassThatHasTheInvokeMethod(Class<T> type) { /* set the field(s) here */ }
```

Then, you can easily provide the `type` to any method call that needs `Class<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I did

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept then, if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Because of type erasure, the type `T` is basically not provided at runtime in any way. The only case in which you can ever retrieve a type `T` is in case of a non-generic class that inherits from a specific case of a generic class (i.e. `Foo extends Bar<Something>`), in this case you can retrieve the `Something`.

In all other cases, unfortunately, you have to use boilerplate - pass the class object explicitly. If any of your constructor arguments is an object of type `T`, you can use `.getClass()` instead to avoid the boilerplate, otherwise you have to pass the class manually.

Comment: Well, in fact you can, if you provide `Something.class` to the `Bar<Something>` instance in constructor or, in case of `Foo`, you could have a no-param constructor that calls `super(Something.class)`. In neither case you need to provide the class of `T` with every method call.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to do to make to make it work, pass the class type as an argument from calling method.

**Quick fix Solution -1**

```
public  T postRequestToService(String endPoint, K requestBean, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
 Class<T> classType) throws  APIException {

 response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endPoint, entity, classType);
```

and in the calling method

```
postRequestToService(endPoint+addOnAvailability, addOnAvailabilityRequest,
httpServletRequest, AddOnAvailabilityResponse.class);
```

***However a better solution is below one - Solution -2***

Define a constructor, even though this happens to be an abstract class

```
public class PegasusService<K, T> {

    private Class<K> requestClass;
    private Class<T> responseClass;

     public PegasusService(Class<K> requestClass, Class<T> responseClass) {
this.requestClass = requestClass;
this.responseClass = responseClass;
}
```

and in the child class pass the class types in the constructor.

```
   AddOnAvailabilityService() {
    super(AddOnAvailabilityRequest.class, AddOnAvailabilityResponse.class);
    }
```

So this code works fine `response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endPoint, entity, responseClass);` No need to pass the class type.

This way we dont have to add an extra argument or change the method definition.

Comment: This is a loser's variant. This is a method of a class that has `<T>` generic type parameter, yet you have to provide the class of `T` in every call. If you provided it to the constructor of the class that I don't know the name of because you excluded it from the code, it would be a lot nicer for the caller.

Comment: Its an abstract class, so I have not defined any constructor .

Comment: That is a poor excuse, abstract classes can have `protected` constructors. Of course you can't instantiate without subclassing.

Comment: This is what I did created a constructor 
public class PegasusService<K, T> {

    private K requestClass;
    private T responseClass;

    public PegasusService(K k, T t) {
 this.setRequestClass(k);
 this.setResponseClass(t);
    }
and in child class
AddOnAvailabilityService(AddOnAvailabilityRequest k, AddOnAvailabilityResponse t) {
 super(k, t);
    }
However 
response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endPoint, entity, responseClass); still giving me same error

Comment: You shouldn't provide the instances themselves, you should provide the classes to the constructor. Like the AddOnAvailabilityResponse.class.

Comment: Thanks, it worked a much better solution indeed. I have updated the answer

Comment: I guess the parameters of `AddOnAvailabilityService` constructor are no longer needed, right? Other than that, this is what i meant, looks good.

Comment: Yeah true, That was auto generated code have corrected it now.